# convert dict keys and values to string

Tags: python-3.x

I am converting every key and value of `dict` of different types into string.

I have tried this code:

```py
def convert_dict_to_str_dict(data_dict):
    converted_dict = {}
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            converted_dict[str(key)] = convert_dict_to_str_dict(value)
        else:
            converted_dict[str(key)] = str(value)
    return converted_dict

data_dict = {
    1: 123,
    'string' : 'this is a string',
    'data' : {
        123: 2345,
        'we' : {
            1: 100,
            2: 'two hundred'
        },
        345 : 15427
    }
}
```

We have to convert above `dict` like represented below.

```
{'1': '123', 'data': {'we': {'1': '100', '2': 'two hundred'}, '345': '15427', '123': '2345'}, 'string': 'this is a string'}
```

Comment: What is the question here, the code is working?

Comment: What is  your problem in this code, it works as your expectations?????